# Property methods vs standalone methods of an object

Tags: javascript, express, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Javascript and sometimes my IDE (VSCode) would suggest properties which are actually methods, and sometimes as just methods. For example I'm using the Express JS framework and there's a method:

```
const app = express();
app.use
```

VSCode would autocomplete to *app.use* without the braces, and tell me it's a property. I have to add the braces manually. However, another method:

```
app.set()
```

Would autocomplete with the braces, and VSCode would indicate its a method in the dropdown.
What is the reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: That just sounds like VSCode isn't properly detecting that `app.use` contains a function and thus needs to be called as a function.

Comment: I tried it with WebStorm and got the same result